# Can't see another computer in WiFi

Tags: wifi

I am trying to do a little experiment and I'm getting pretty odd results that I can't explain. I came to my University with my friend, we both brought our laptops and we connected to the same WiFi. But from some reason, our computers couldn't communicate with each other. For example, I couldn't ping him, and I when I did an ARP Scan to find all the hosts on the LAN I didn't find him. He did the same. He couldn't ping me and he didn't find my laptop when he did an ARP scan. Yet, there were many other devices on the LAN that both of us could ping and that we both found in our ARP scan. The University may be big, but we sat just next to each other.

I know that the WiFi on the university may be complex, but yet I have no explanations of what is happening. We sit next to each other, connect to the same WiFi(same Access Point MAC), we both see many same devices in our LAN, yet we can't see each other. Anyone has any idea of what may be happening? Why can't we see/ping each other while we are on the same LAN?

Thanks! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wireless access point probably has a security setting of "Wireless Isolation Within SSID" turned on.  This function does exactly what you describe.  It allows all authenticated users to see machines on the LAN, but not other wireless machines on the same access point.

Comment: Hmm Okay, It seems to explain these results indeed.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure your router and make some settings like this

```
LAN DHCP=Enable
Wireless Authentication type=WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK
Encryption=AES
```

After this setting delete all Wireless network of router listed in your PC. And than connect, It will works. you can ping your both PC together.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are connected to an infrastructure mode access point (99% of APs), in order to send packets to another device your laptop sends the packet to the AP (to the distribution system), and then the AP sends the packet to your friend (from the distribution system).  You cannot connect 'directly' to your friend.

The AP can direct whether or not wireless clients can see each other - depending on the manufacturer this can be implemented in many different ways.  You could talk to your system administrator about why/how this policy works.